# motioneye: motion detect small objects (insects / roaches)

Tags: raspbian, camera

I'm using the latest version of motioneye.
I'm trying to detect cock coaches with the size of about 3 ~ 4 cm. 
I played around with the motion detection featured offered in the web-interface of motioneye (especially motion threashold).  But I could not make it detect my moving fake-cockroach (a black earaser).

Is there any other special option to tweak? or is it simply not possible to detect these things?

Answer (score 1):

Motion detection works by seeing changes in pixels. You have to provide a stable background that contrasts strongly with the subject.  Cockroaches are dark, so your detection will improve with a white background. Constant illumination is also good. High contrast helps detection.

Also, the illumination has to be compatible with the camera. If you have an IR camera, you can illuminate with IR. iF you have a normal camera, continuous visible illumination works but may prevent cockroaches from entering the field of view.

The subject has to consume a significant portion of the field of view. A cockroach from 6ft away won't be noticed. A cockroach at 12 inches will change more pixels and trigger capture.

Lastly, your fake cockroach test must be preceded by a long period of non-activity where nothing happens in the field of view.

Comment: Are there published specifications for these factors? What is "high" contrast, how many pixels need change, etc?

Comment: Judging from all the recent self-driving car crashes, I think they're still trying to figure out the factors. :D

There are usually settings that correspond to each of the mentioned qualities, but every vendor and product will have their own buzzwords. For example, I use "motion", which has parameters such as this: http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/ConfigOptionEventGap With the above conceptual model, you should be able to figure out what you need for your particular setup.